# Changing axis in the excel graph

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I have data like this

5,10044E-06

5,11055E-06

5,11019E-06……

And I got this:

[image]

And I need to have axis like this:
[image]

So instead 0 I need 10^1… and instead of 0,000001 I need 1. How can I do it? Am I making mistakes in my data or I can just change somehow my axis in excel?

Answer (score 0):

The easier way is to create a new column with the actual values you want to plot (for the y-values). So you will another column with the values (just multiply it by 1e6):

```
5,10044
5,11055
5,11019
```

And plot these values instead

Answer (score 0):

This might help!

Right click the vertical axis -> 'format axis' -> axis options -> [display units](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HpcWo.jpg)